# Aligning a li element in an Inline-block defined Width set up

Tags: html-lists, vertical-alignment

this might be a very basic question, but i wonder what is the proper way to align vertically this elements, i have this image: http://s22.postimg.org/luh1ory8x/ul_li_vertical_align.png

This explains my problem in a more visual way, the CSS final set up is something like this:

```
.ulclass li { display: inline-block; width: 130px; height: 40px; text-align: center; padding: 5px; vertical-align: middle;  }
```

the HTML is a simple

```
 textextext
```

set up, with different lengths of text so that is why they break into more lines and other just have single lines of text etc.

Answer (score 1):

Must of the times does not work as we expected to, since we always try to vertically center content on a page.This is because CSS vertical-align attribute is used to specify two completely different behaviors depending on where it is used.

1. vertical-align in table cells:
   When used in table cells, vertical-align does what most people expect it to. So in most of the cases(if possible) the solution is set the parent display attribute to table, table-cell, or something related depending on what you really want.
2. vertical-align on inline elements:
   When vertical-align is applied to inline elements, however, it's a whole new behavior . In this situation, it behaves like the (old, deprecated) align attribute did on  elements.
3. Other cases:
   Doesn't really work.
   In this case you need to look for other solutions like:

   - Specify the parent container as position:relative or position:absolute.
   - Specify a fixed height on the child container.
   - Set position:absolute and top:50% on the child container to move the top down to the middle of the parent.
   - Set margin-top:-yy where yy is half the height of the child container to offset the item up.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to support old versions of IE then I suggest you look into 'flexbox' this should be able to do what you need:

http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately i need the IE support, starting from IE8 at least.

Comment: OK plan B, have you tried placing the text inside a span and then setting 'display:table' on the parent? That way you can use vertical alignment on the span and style the span with the background colour you want.

Comment: like this: <ul><li><span>text</li><ul>
ul {display:table}
li { display:table-cell;vertical-align:middle;}
li span { background-colour:#f00; }

Comment: I've done tweaks like that adding classes to specific li's (the single lined ones)  , but i am wondering about a "legit" way of aligning those.

Comment: Display: table is perfectly legit, using actual tables would be poor practice but setting something to display:table is fine. 

What you are trying to do is actually quite uncommon though (usually the text is vertically aligned but the boxes are equal height) and often in these circumstances, unorthodox requirements require unorthodox solutions. :)